# help to build a private cloud with ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, cloud

Any body please guide me to build a private cloud using ubuntu server 14.04 in a lab with 3 computers. i need step by step guidance from starting.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Openstack the installation guide has Step-by-Step guidance and ubuntu 14.04 comes with the actuall version (juno).

http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/

Comment: i am new to ubuntu, so not getting clearly that what the document want to say- actually i have 3pc. please make me understand how should i start with the installation.

Comment: Hm, installing a private cloud is not that trivial and new to ubuntu is not a good starting point. How familiar are you with ubuntu (or linux in general) administration. Maybe first, what did you like to accomplish with your "private cloud"? Play around with cloud software or use it to provide you with virtual machines.

Comment: my purpose is just build a private cloud using open stack. but i am not getting the right way , where and how to start?

Comment: Ok then you got two options, installing it from packages and configure it by hand or go for an automated installation. 
If you are new to ubuntu i would recommend to go for the second option an try e.g. http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/ 
Others like ubuntu maas or rackspace private cloud usually require an additional installtion server, so i would go for devstack. Maybe try it in virtual machines first.

Comment: actually i have to demonstrate a private cloud in my lab, but problem is with how to start. Linux administration is not a big issue. i have started with ubuntu server 12.04 and got stuck in GPG error : NODATA 1 NODATA2 issue while updating. and then i asked for solution, for which i was suggested here to install 14.04 instead of continue with 12.04. So that's why i am asking?

Comment: installation from packages means ( installing the individul compute etc services after installtion of server). am i right?

Comment: But i have to add that for a 3 Server installation, if you really want to use the  virtualization and not just for playing around with openstack. Installing a private cloud is an overkill. If you like to use the servers for virtualization i would recommend to go for a KVM/Qemu virtualization and use virt-manager for remote administration.

Comment: actually i am not getting you properly. i am simply asking " if i have 3 pc and want to develop a private cloud using a open source (openstack) then how should i proceed? what should be step 1 followed by others.

Comment: yes you are right installing from packages ist service wise (identity -- keystone, nova -- compute, neutron -- networking). In this case your setup would probabliy be: One server as controller and networking node and the two others as compute nodes.

Comment: First thing would be to install ubuntu on all machines and then prepare the networks. Usually the Network/Controll node needs 3 Networks (or Vlans if only one nic is available), one for external, one controll network and one for the instance tunnels.  The compute nodes will need 2 networks, controll and instance-tunnel. You need to establish Nating/IP-Forwaring on the controller in order to acces the insternet from the compute nodes.
Then you should be ready to do the installation as described in the installation guide. Just start with mysql/rabbitmq etc.

Comment: Look here this is the devstack guide for multiple nodes. I would recommed to follow this guide for a first installtion to get an idea of what has to be done. http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/guides/multinode-lab.html
If you succeed, you could give the package based installation a try. In this case you have to install and configure all services (around 10) manually, maybe this is not the best idea for a first installation.

Comment: exactly. i have started with first pc on which i have installed server 12.04 and begin with first task update. it gave me error message of NODATA1 AND NODATA2 invalid signature. I skipped this step and proceed with instllation of bridge utils, it reverted with unable to locate package bridge utils and same problem while installing mysql-server? now how to resolve it.. Further the pc which i have taken for controller node having only one NIC (eth 0).

Comment: Can you please post the full error message? Looks like you are missing some of the keys needed to sign package information.

Comment: 1-sudo apt-get udpate  Error message " E: GPG : http://security.ubuntu.com: precise security release : invalid signature : NODATA1 NODATA 2....    2- sudo apt-get install ntp ; error message : unable to locate ntp. 3- sudo apt-get install bridge-utils ; error message : Unable to locate bridge utils. 4- same with mysql-server package

Comment: Hm weird, are you behind a firewall? Can you ping  security.ubuntu.com?

Comment: i didn't check for firewall ping...can you please tell me how should i directly contact you.

Comment: yup? can you please give me your own id on google +

Comment: i have ping security.ubuntu.com  output is : PING security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.13) 56(84) bytes of data...and cursor keeps on blinking